# Devexpress Xtrareports databound generates (unwanted) pagebreak after each record

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, xtrareport

Using devexpress xtrareports version 11.2 I have setup a databound report using a temporary table. I bind the content to a single xrrichttext on the report.

Each record is generated and each next record starts on a new page. Now I want to lose the automatic pagebreak and implement my own logic for breaking.

But I have not yet been able to drop the auto-break. I went through all the pagebreak properties in design mode but everything is already set to none.

Besides the xrrichtext there is also a xrpanel which contains a xrlabel, all are set to a low height as default with cangrow/canshrink to true.

Is there something specific I can set for this or am I still missing something?

edit:
I am using the detailband, I had given the xrrichtext a minimal height after realizing this might be the problem, but this didnot seem to help. But after I restarted this did however fix the problem.

But now my own pagebreaks are not working as expected, not sure if I should start another question for this.

In the detailband I have added a xrpagebreak.
In the detail_beforeprint I check if the current records needs a pagebreak

```
    If GetCurrentColumnValue("break") = True Then
        xrPageBreak1.Visible = True
    Else
        xrPageBreak1.Visible = False
    End If
```

Only now I am getting a pagebreak for every record, doesnot seem to react on the value for field 'break'?

Answer (score 0):

which reportband are you using?

some report bands only appear once on every page, usually data is added to the detail band, this is displayed until the page is full. or until you break the page yourself